# getting Create Error when using Powershell

Tags: powershell, document-set

I am receiving this error on following line

> Exception calling "Create" with "4" argument(s): "Value cannot be
>   null. Parameter name: parentFolder" At
>   x:\Dev\PowerShell\MoveFiles2DocSet.ps1:29 char:91
>   +         $newDocumentSet =
>   [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet]::Create
>   <<<< ($docLib.RootFo lder,$DocSet,$cType.Id,$docsetProperties)
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [],
>   MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

```
$newDocumentSet = [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet]::Create($docLib.RootFolder,$DocSet,$cType.Id,$docsetProperties)

$siteURL="http://intranet.colgate.com/sites/blazingWhite"          
$docLib = "NewProduct"
$site=Get-SPSite $siteURL
$web=$site.RootWeb
$collFiles=$web.GetFolder($docLib).Files
$count=$collFiles.Count
while($count -ne 0)
{
$item = $collFiles[$count-1].Item
## Create document set if it does not exists
$DocSet = $item["CounterParty"]
$DocSetURL = $siteURL + "/" + $docLib + "/" + $DocSet
$docLibURL = $siteURL + "/" + $docLib
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder]$targetFolder = $web.GetFolder($DocSetURL)
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder]$doclibFolder = $web.GetFolder($docLibURL)
Write-Host ""
Write-Host $DocSet
Write-Host $targetFolder
Write-Host $doclibFolder

  if (-not $targetFolder.Exists)
    {   # Create Doc Set    
        # Get Document Set Content Type from list   
            $cType = $web.ContentTypes["Document Set"]
        # Create Document Set Properties Hashtable          
            [Hashtable]$docsetProperties = @{"Title"=$DocSet}
            $docsetProperties = @{"Description"=$DocSet}
            $docsetProperties = @{"CounterParty"=$DocSet}

            Write-Host $cType.Id   
            Write-Host $docsetProperties
            Write-Host ""
        # Create new Document Set

        $newDocumentSet = [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet]::Create($doclibFolder,$DocSet,$cType.Id,$docsetProperties)
        Write-Host "Document set created " $newDocumentSet

        if($newDocumentSet.Exists)
        {
            # changing folder type to Document Set type
            $newDocumentSet.Item["ContentTypeId"] = $cType.Id
            $newDocumentSet.Item["HTML File Type"] = "SharePoint.DocumentSet"
            $newDocumentSet.Item.Update()
        }

    } 

# move file(s) to the document set
    Write-Host "$DocSet is the doc set. $collFiles[$count-1].Name is name"
    $collFiles[$count-1].MoveTo($siteURL + "/" + $docLib + "/" + $DocSet + "/"  + $collFiles[$count-1].Name, $true)                       
$count--
}

#dispose:
    $web.Dispose();    
    $site.Dispose();
```

Edit:

The above code is working except document set looks like Folder instead of blue doc set icon. Can anyone shed some light on this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by looking at your code.

```
Create($docLib.RootFolder,$DocSet,$cType.Id,$docsetProperties)
```

and `$docLib` is string?

```
$docLib = "NewProduct"
```

maybe this would work

```
Create($targetFolder,$DocSet,$cType.Id,$docsetProperties)
```

since

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder]$targetFolder = $web.GetFolder($DocSetURL)
```

Comment: hmm. still gettting same error. Exception calling "Create" with "4" argument(s): "<nativehr>0x80070002</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>"
At C:\Dev\PowerShell\MoveFiles2DocSet.ps1:38 char:91
+         $newDocumentSet = [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet]::Create <<<< ($targetFolder,
$DocSet,$cType.Id,$docsetProperties)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: Please update your original question with an updated code sample to reflect Vedran's solution. Your code above does not have 38 lines (though your error occurs at line 38).

Comment: Actually the error on this line $newDocumentSet = [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet]::Create($docLib.RootFolder,$DocSet,$cType.Id,$docsetProperties)

Comment: I have bunch of comments that's why my line and posted line are out of sync

Comment: Well Verdan has you on the right track. First, make sure none of your parameters are null (write them out to the screen to ensure their values), and make sure that their types are correct.

Comment: @Tim: Yes sir, I wrote it out to screen and they are well populated. now what?

Comment: DocumentSet..::.Create Method (SPFolder, String, SPContentTypeId, Hashtable, Boolean, SPUser) I am not passing the bool and user

Comment: [DocumentSet.Create Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.documentmanagement.documentsets.documentset.create.aspx) has 3 overloads and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee574540.aspx) is one you used in code you provided. No bool, no user.

Comment: I see an accepted user, but I'm curious as to what the solution was if the above answer was not sufficient?

Comment: I would like to make above code functional for future reference. Without that this question is useless. I will look at it tomorrow if no additional replays are posted...

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of late to this particular party, but while researching my own issue with document sets appearing as simple folders I came across this blog entry                  ( http://aknauer.blogspot.com/2011/06/document-sets-und-powershell.html ) which contained this valuable nugget:

> "It is also important that you select the content type $cType from the
>   collection of the list and not from the collection of the Web.
>   Otherwise, rather than just a document set a new folder is created."

I switched my content type assignment from the web collection (as Mala had done) to the list collection (as Andreas suggests) and my problem was resolved.