# How to create Document Set?

Tags: document-set

I am following this post on here [getting Create Error when using Powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19377/getting-create-error-when-using-powershell) to create Document Set.

The script is creating regular yellow folder. However, I can create Document Set using UI in a document library.

Answer (score 1):

Followed this article and it helped to resolved my issue.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.documentmanagement.documentsets.documentset.create.aspx

Thanks